# Where can I find records about accidents in the South Vietnam Air Force?

Tags: accidents, accident-investigation, ntsb

I don't know if this is the right place for this question, but I guess it's related to aviation right?

My grand uncle was a pilot in the South Vietnam Air Force. He served from 1964 to 1968. He flew F-5s and A-37s and crashed on a A-37.

Being I student pilot now, I very much want to look back and find out what really caused his crash. My family fled Vietnam from the Communists when I was too young. I only remember seeing his Air Force Death Certificate in English which I didn't understand a word in it back then. I was told from multiple sources that his A37 blew up before taking off, and that he crashed soon after take-off... But I always wanted to see the actual result of an investigation if any.

Do you think it is even possible to look up records for those dead ones who served for the South of Vietnam? (since I know they are considered forgotten in the history of the Vietnam War)

The information about the accident that I can remember:
Date and time of the accident: 12/10/1968 9AM
Location: Pleiku Airbase, Vietnam
Aircraft: A-37
Name of pilot: Hai, Le Nguyen (Lê Nguyên Hải)
Pilot's rank: Lieutenant
Pilot's DOB: 12/09/1941

Thanks.

Comment: May be you have to ask history.se

Comment: That's going too be a tough one. There's no telling if any records from the south Vietnam air force survived the war. If the US Air Force investigated the accident they may have records of it. The US military keeps some pretty meticulous records. The place to contact would be the [national archives](http://www.archives.gov/research/military/air-force/). Remember that they have LOTS of records that have not been made available on the net.

Comment: Another organization I ran across is the [A-37 Association](http://a-37.org) There's some email addresses on their site. The US a-37 pilots at the time were training the Vietnamese pilots and I'm sure worked closely with them. They might be able to steer you in the right direction. The last thing any veteran wants to see is another veteran of any nationality be forgotten.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, guys. I'll contact the suggested sources for more info.